# Filter the single column of an Dataframe from another dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

DataFrame1 :

```
   origin        2001-01-01 00:00:00  2002-01-01 00:00:00  2003-01-01 00:00:00  2004-01-01 00:00:00  ...  2008-01-01 00:00:00  2009-01-01 00:00:00  2010-01-01 00:00:00   Grand Total
    Simulation 1         1.597942e+13                  NaN         1.114312e+20         4.370424e+26  ...         3.633710e+52         3.388095e+58         1.103886e+64  3.159025e+71    
    Simulation 2         1.852542e+13                  NaN         1.280181e+20         4.958904e+26  ...         7.830853e+52         1.077502e+59         5.605342e+64  1.852667e+72    
    Simulation 3         1.978941e+13                  NaN         1.024391e+20         5.038746e+26  ...         6.922672e+52         9.431727e+58         5.947689e+63  4.921311e+71    
    Simulation 4         1.845122e+13                  NaN         1.050210e+20         4.305396e+26  ...         6.529340e+52         1.004737e+59         4.311079e+63  6.250895e+71    
    Simulation 5         1.733954e+13                  NaN         1.082353e+20         4.400699e+26  ...         4.554812e+52         2.587384e+58         5.571276e+63  1.459044e+71
```

Im trying to filter the cloumn Grand Total from the above Dataframe1.

DataFrame2 :

```
 CI           Var
0  60.0  2.059017e+72
1  70.0  2.402186e+72
2  80.0  2.745356e+72
3  90.5  3.105684e+72
```

In DataFrame2, in Column Var first value is 2.059017e+72, now we have to collect the values from Grand Total column of DataFrame1 which is greater than 2.059017e+72 and store it in the separate dataframe, for each value of var..

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the columns like this:

```
DataFrame3 = DataFrame1.loc[DataFrame2['Var'][0] < DataFrame1['Grand Total']]
```

Do you want to print the values or save them as an extra column of df2?

Comment: No i need it in separate dataframe

Comment: @sanath, I cannot locate "Grand Total column of DataFrame2" as stated in your post, while none of the Grand Total column of DataFrame1 is greater than 2.059017e+72

Comment: Please somebody help me out

Comment: Please read what Black Raven wrote; 1.852667e+72 is the largest in df1 which is smaller than all of the values in df2 Var. How do you want to return anything which is larger than the values in df2?